# How to pass the information scanned from a QR Code in differente <input>?

Tags: javascript, html, qr-code

I have a QR code scanner. It reads the code perfectly. Now i want to pass the scanned information to different input fields. For example: I have a QR code and when you scan it shows the name, surname, number etc. I want to show the different data that I have scanned from the code in different input fields and next save on submit. I want to know if there is any way do this? Thank you in advance for your time.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsQRreader.js"></script>

<div id="loadingMessage"> Unable to access video stream (please make sure you have a webcam enabled)</div>
<canvas id="canvas" hidden></canvas>
<div id="output" hidden>
  <div id="outputMessage">No QR code detected.</div>
    <textarea type="text" id="outputData" name="outputData" value="" style="width: 200px;margin-left:25px;"> 
    </textarea>
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">

        </div>


<script>
            var video = document.createElement("video");
            var canvasElement = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var canvas = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
            var loadingMessage = document.getElementById("loadingMessage");
            var outputContainer = document.getElementById("output");
            var outputMessage = document.getElementById("outputMessage");
            var outputData = document.getElementById("outputData");

            function drawLine(begin, end, color) {
              canvas.beginPath();
              canvas.moveTo(begin.x, begin.y);
              canvas.lineTo(end.x, end.y);
              canvas.lineWidth = 4;
              canvas.strokeStyle = color;
              canvas.stroke();
            }

            // Use facingMode: environment to attemt to get the front camera on phones
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { facingMode: "environment" } }).then(function(stream) {
              video.srcObject = stream;
              video.setAttribute("playsinline", true); // required to tell iOS safari we don't want fullscreen
              video.play();
              requestAnimationFrame(tick);
            });

            function tick() {
              loadingMessage.innerText = "Loading video..."
              if (video.readyState === video.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA) {
                loadingMessage.hidden = true;
                canvasElement.hidden = false;
                outputContainer.hidden = false;

                canvasElement.height = video.videoHeight;
                canvasElement.width = video.videoWidth;
                canvas.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
                var imageData = canvas.getImageData(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
                var code = jsQR(imageData.data, imageData.width, imageData.height, {
                  inversionAttempts: "dontInvert",
                });
                if (code) {
                  drawLine(code.location.topLeftCorner, code.location.topRightCorner, "#FF3B58");
                  drawLine(code.location.topRightCorner, code.location.bottomRightCorner, "#FF3B58");
                  drawLine(code.location.bottomRightCorner, code.location.bottomLeftCorner, "#FF3B58");
                  drawLine(code.location.bottomLeftCorner, code.location.topLeftCorner, "#FF3B58");
                  outputMessage.hidden = false;
                  outputData.parentElement.hidden = false;
                  outputData.value = code.data;
     } 
    }
   requestAnimationFrame(tick);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It would help to know how the data is structured.

Comment: `different input fields` what inputs exactly?

Comment: @MoshFeu I want to pass scanned QR code: name in <input type="text" id="name" readonly>, the surname in <input type="text"  id="surname" readonly>.

Comment: Ok. And what you expect that `code.data` will be? I mean what is the value of that QR? A url? An object?

Comment: The QR code contains Full Name, Address and the number. It is only a text. The result i want is an <input type="text"> with the full name, another <input type="text"> with the address and another <input type="text"> with the number

Comment: How? A JSON object? Something like that? `{"fullName": "My full name", "address": "an address", "number": "a number"}` if not, can you post what text is in the `outputData` textarea after the bardcode found?